# How to calculate C(n, k) % 3?

Tags: algorithm, modulo, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

**UPDATE: C(n, k) means `Binomial Coefficient`**

I'm dealing with a number theory problem. I've transformed the big problem into a simple problem:  **How to calculate `C(n,k)%3`, for which n<=10^15.** There are about `m ( <= 10 000 )` data-set needed to calculate within **1 second**.

The way I solve it is using the [`Lucas' theorem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem). It's `O(m log n)`. And it's fast enough to solve the problem. But I'm wondering **if there is a better solution to this problem, and even to `n <= 10^100` or `m <= 1 000 000`**?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI O(m log n) is considered pretty "quick" usually.

Comment: For n=10^100, using Lucas' thm only requires log n = 100 * log_3 10. Even m=1 000 000 at the same time, it's fast enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating Binomial Coefficient (nCk) for large n & k](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k)

Comment: I think this should be reopened because we don't have to calculate the binomial coefficient at all, we just have to compute the prime factors raised to a power modulo 3, and we know the prime factors of factorial like http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2011/07/evaluating-factorial-from-its-prime.html

Comment: you can use dynamic programming to calculate this.