# Sequence of n numbers - compute all possible k-subsequence of "lucky" numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem with one task, so if you could help me a little bit.

> Numbers are "lucky" or "unlucky". Number is "lucky" just if every
>   digit 7 
>        or every digit is 4.  So "lucky" numbers are for example 4, 44, 7, 77. 
>        "Unlucky" are the others numbers.
>        You will get sequence of n-elements and number K. Your task is to
>        compute number of all possible k-elements subsequence, which fulfill a one 
>        condition. The condition is that in the subsequence mustn't be two same "lucky"
>        numbers. So for example there mustn't  77 and 77...
>        Output number of all possible k-elements subsequence mod 10^9+7
>        0 < N,K < 10^5
>
> ```
> Few examples:
> Input:
>
> 5 2
> 7 7 3 7 77
> Output:
>
> 7
>
> Input:
>
> 5 3
> 3 7 77 7 77
> Output:
>
> 4
>
> Input:
>
> 34 17
> 14 14 14 ... 14 14 14
> Output:
>
> 333606206
> ```

I have code which seems to work, but it is too slow when I try to compute binomial coefficient. I'm using map. In string I store number in string format. In second - int - part of the map is number which represents how many times was that number(in the first map parameter) used. So now I have stored every "unlucky" numbers stored together. Also every same "lucky" number is together. When I have it stored like this, I just compute all multiplications. For example:

```
Input 
5 2
3 7 7 77 7
Are stored like this:  map["other"] = 1 map["7"] = 3 map["77"] = 1 
Because k = 2 --> result is: 1*3 + 1*1 + 1*3 = 7.
```

I think problem is with computing binomial coefficient. For the third example it needs to compute (34 choose 17) and it is computing very long time.I've found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106587/binomial-coefficient-modulo-142857) , but I don't understand how they are solving this problem.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
    // Base Cases
    if (k == 0 || k == n)
        return 1;

    // Recur
    return  binomialCoeff(n - 1, k - 1) + binomialCoeff(n - 1, k);
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    map<string, int> mapa;  // create map, string is a number, int represents number of used string-stored numbers ---> so if 7 was used two times, in the map it will be stored like this mapa["7"] == 2 and so on)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // I will load number as string, if this number is "lucky" - digist are all 7 or all 4
    {                            // every "unlucky" numbers are together, as well as all same "lucky" numbers ---> so 77 and 77 will be stored in one element....
        string number;
        cin >> number;
        char digit = number[0];
        bool lucky = false;
        if (digit == '7' || digit == '4')
            lucky = true;
        for (int j = 1; j < number.length(); j++) {
            if (digit != '7' && digit != '4')
                break;
            if (number[j] != digit) {
                lucky = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (lucky)
            mapa[number]++;
        else
            mapa["other"]++;
    }
    vector<bool> v(mapa.size());
    bool lack = k > mapa.size(); //lack of elements in map --> it is when mapa.size() < k; i. e. number of elements in array can't make k-element subsequence.
    int rest = lack ? k - mapa.size() + 1 : 1;  // how many elements from "unlucky" numbers I must choose, so it makes base for binomial coefficient (n choose rest)
    if (lack)  //if lack is true, different size of vector
        fill(v.begin() + mapa.size(), v.end(), true);
    else
        fill(v.begin() + k, v.end(), true);
    int *array = new int[mapa.size()];   //easier to manipulate with array for me
    int sum = 0;  
    int product = 1;
    int index = 0; 
    for (map<string, int> ::iterator pos = mapa.begin(); pos != mapa.end(); ++pos)  // create array from map
    {
        if (lack && pos->first == "other") {    //if lack of elements in map, the number in elemets representing "unlucky" numbers will be binomial coefficient (mapa["other] choose rest)
            array[index++] = binomialCoeff(mapa["other"], rest);
            continue;
        }
        array[index++] = pos->second;
    }
    do {   // this will create every posible multiplication for k-elements subsequences
        product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mapa.size(); ++i) {
            if (!v[i]) {
                product *= array[i];
            }
        }
        sum += product;
    } while (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    if (mapa["other"] >= k && mapa.size() > 1) {   // if number of "unlucky" numbers is bigger than k, we need to compute all possible  k-elements subsequences just from "unlucky" number, so binomial coefficient (mapa["other] choose k)
        sum += binomialCoeff(mapa["other"], k);
    }
    cout << sum % 1000000007 << endl;
}
```

Comment: First things first. Find a different method for computing binomial coefficients (google for it). You are using just about the worst possible method imaginable. Bear in mind that binomial coefficients you need will overflow `int` in your examples.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106587/binomial-coefficient-modulo-142857) , but I don't understand how to do it. It needs to be very fast, I suppose, 'cause in my case, both 0 < N,K <= 10^5

Comment: This looks like a perfect match for being solved in a haskell oneliner :/

Comment: What is the range of number in the sequence?

Comment: Some hint: the number of distinct lucky number will be small, only less than 1000 numbers (maximum 9 digits, so 2^9 + 2^8 + ... + 2 ~ 1000), which you can use dynamic programming to calculate the lucky number part. For unlucky number part, as we only need to calculate 1000 [combinations](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm),  We can use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to handle.

Comment: You're right. In fact, there are just 18 types of lucky numbers, aren't there? 4,44,444....444444444 and the same for 7. Also, I don't understand how to use Fermat's little theorem to compute combinations.

Comment: For combination `C(a, b) = a! / (b! (a - b)!)`, and we need to calculate `C(a, b) mod 10^9 + 7`, we can not directly calculate the mod of C(a, b), however, notice that 10^9 + 7 is a prime number, so, we can use the theorem, see one explanation [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5679)

Comment: So, I've found [this article](https://codeaccepted.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/output-the-answer-modulo-109-7/), and now I have code, that works just fine :)

Comment: Great :), next time, please use `@` + `Name` to notify the person you are talking to, for example @PhamTrung to notify me :D

Comment: @PhamTrung thanks, i will remember that :)