# Finding binomial coefficient for large n and k modulo m

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulus, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I want to compute nCk mod m with following constraints:

n<=10^18

k<=10^5

m=10^9+7

I have read this article:

[Calculating Binomial Coefficient (nCk) for large n & k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k)

But here value of m is 1009. Hence using Lucas theorem, we need only to calculate 1009*1009 different values of aCb where a,b<=1009

How to do it with above constraints.
I cannot make a array of O(m*k) space complexity with given constraints.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the fact that

```
(n, k) = n! / k! / (n - k)! = n*(n-1)*...*(n-k+1)/[k*(k-1)*...*1]
```

so you actually have just `2*k=2*10^5` factors. For the inverse of a number you can use suggestion of **kfx** since your `m` is prime.

Comment: Right, for the OP's small k this will work, but will not generalize for larger values.

Comment: @kfx Can you please explain, why this will not work for larger values?

Comment: @LVK I can: imagine just (1000, 200) for C++. The result is too big (you can't store it in any default c++ data).

Answer (score 5):

The binominal coefficient of `(n, k)` is calculated by the formula:

```
(n, k) = n! / k! / (n - k)!
```

To make this work for large numbers `n` and `k` modulo `m` observe that:

1. Factorial of a number modulo `m` can be calculated step-by-step, in
   each step taking the result `% m`. However, this will be far too slow with n up to 10^18. So there are [faster methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime) where the complexity is bounded by the modulo, and you can use some of those.
2. The division `(a / b) mod m` is equal to `(a * b^-1) mod m`, where `b^-1` is the inverse of `b` modulo `m` (that is, `(b * b^-1 = 1) mod m`).

This means that:

```
(n, k) mod m = (n! * (k!)^-1 * ((n - k)!)^-1) mod m
```

The inverse of a number can be efficiently found using the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Assuming you have the factorial calculation sorted out, the rest of the algorithm is straightforward, just watch out for integer overflows on multiplication. Here's reference code that works up to `n=10^9`. To handle for larger numbers the factorial computation should be replaced with a more efficient algorithm and the code should be slightly adapted to avoid integer overflows, but the main idea will remain the same:

```
#define MOD 1000000007

// Extended Euclidean algorithm
int xGCD(int a, int b, int &x, int &y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }

    int x1, y1, gcd = xGCD(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (long long)(a / b) * y1;
    return gcd;
}

// factorial of n modulo MOD
int modfact(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        result = (long long)result * n % MOD;
        n -= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// multiply a and b modulo MOD
int modmult(int a, int b) {
    return (long long)a * b % MOD;
}

// inverse of a modulo MOD
int inverse(int a) {
    int x, y;
    xGCD(a, MOD, x, y);
    return x;
}

// binomial coefficient nCk modulo MOD
int bc(int n, int k)
{
    return modmult(modmult(modfact(n), inverse(modfact(k))), inverse(modfact(n - k)));
}
```

Comment: `modfact` will "never" halt for `n = 10^18`

Comment: @iggy the code is a simple sketch that works for up to 10^9 as mentioned, not a complete implementation of what the OP needs.

Comment: @kfx There is something wrong. For `n=5` and `k=0` and `mod=17` it gives me correctly `1`. However for `n=55` and `k` and `mod` as before it gives me `0`, but again it should be `1`.

Comment: It seams it always gives `0` for `n>mod`

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to pre-compute and store all the possible aCb values! they can be computed per case.

Second, for the special case when (k < m) and (n < m^2), the Lucas theorem easily reduces to the following result:

(n choose k) mod m = ((n mod m) choose k) mod m

then since (n mod m) < 10^9+7 you can simply use the code proposed by @kfx.

Answer (score 3):

We want to compute nCk (mod p). I'll handle when 0 <= k <= p-2, because Lucas's theorem handles the rest.

**Wilson's theorem** states that for prime p, (p-1)! = -1 (mod p), or equivalently (p-2)! = 1 (mod p) (by division).

By division: (k!)^(-1) = (p-2)!/(k!) = (p-2)(p-3)...(k+1) (mod p)

Thus, the binomial coefficient is n!/(k!(n-k)!) = n(n-1)...(n-k+1)/(k!) = n(n-1)...(n-k+1)(p-2)(p-3)...(k+1) (mod p)

Voila. You don't have to do any inverse computations or anything like that. It's also fairly easy to code. A couple optimizations to consider: (1) you can replace (p-2)(p-3)... with (-2)(-3)...; (2) nCk is symmetric in the sense that nCk = nC(n-k) so choose the half that requires you to do less computations.

Comment: 0

Excellent! It's way too late to help OP, but it gave me ideas about solving a different problem.