# Efficient way to find number of sums possible

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, time

Given three integers `n`, `k` and `d`, how many ways can `n` be represented as sum of positive integers `i<=k`, such that `d` occurs at least once in the sum. It is guarenteed that `0<d<=k`. My approach was a recursive one;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int n,k,d,ans=0;
void solve(int totw,int flag)//totw is the total sum till now, and flag is to keep track of the number of d's in the sum.
{
    if(totw>n)
        return;
    if(totw==n && flag>0)//flag>0--->at least 1 d
    {
        ans = (ans+1)%1000000007;//answer is expected modulo 10^9+7
        return;
    }
    int i=1,h=k;
    if(h>n-totw)
        h=n-totw;
    while(i<=h)
    {
        if(i==d)
            flag++;
        solve(totw+i,flag);
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&k,&d);
    solve(0,0);
    printf("%d",ans);
}
```

Input:
3 3 2
Output:
2
But the judge shows `Time Limit Exceeded`. Is there any more efficient algorithm to proceed with in this case? `0<n,k<=100`
PS:I was just wondering whether there is any combinatoric argument that can solve this question without `recursion` or `iteration`. And yes....**order of sums** **matter**.

Comment: Constraints for n and k?

Comment: @SergeyS `0<n,k<=100`

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but isn't the problem same as computing the number of ways (n-d) can be represented as a sum of i integers where i <= k-1?

Comment: Order for sum matters? if `n==3+5` and `n==5+3` are two different ways, or only one counts?

Comment: @SergeyS...order of sums matter..

Comment: @AbhishekBansal...I don't think that was the question. Also `d` can occur many times in the sum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Do you have some test example input and outputs?

Comment: @chux.....done :)

Comment: @FrankS101...I too think memoization is what I may need here.....could you suggest how it can be implemented here?

Comment: "Input:
3 3 2
Output:
3" is unclear.  Are not only {1,2} and {2,1} the only **2** valid solutions unlike **3** in your example?  Looks like your functionality is incorrect as I think it also counts {1,1,1} or {3} as a valid solution.  As commented below, get functionality correct and _then_ improve efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your recursive calls as a graph. Each node is given by the parameters of your function `(totw, flag)`, and you add an edge whenever you make a recursive call. There are about `n*2` nodes and `n*2*k` edges in this graph.

This graph has a very interesting property: it is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (e.g. because `totw` is strictly increasing at each call). Therefore, when you call `solve(totw, flag)`, you can keep the result in an array, so that you don't compute it twice.

This is actually a way to explain [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming): an algorithm to find the shortest path in a DAG (with slight modifications it can also compute the longest path/the number of paths, but you get the idea). The time complexity on a graph `G = (V, E)` will be a `O(|V|+|E|)` (that's actually a kind of [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)).

Thus, keeping the results in an array will result in a `O(nk)` time complexity.

Actually you can make the implementation even shorter by changing slightly the graph:

```
enum { UNKNOWN = -1 };

/* not tested */
/* solve(num, d_seen): returns the answer to the problem with a sum
   target, knowing whether `d` was already used */
int solve(int sum, int d_seen)
{
  if (sum == 0) return d_seen;
  int ans = dp[sum][d_seen];
  if (ans == UNKNOWN) {
    ans = 0;
    /* min(a, b) being what it is supposed to be */
    for (int i = 1; i <= min(sum, k); ++i)
      ans = (ans + solve(sum - i, d_seen || (i == d))) % MOD;
  }

  return (dp[sum][d_seen] = ans);
}
```

By the way you don't put `flag` back to 0 after incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this Wikipedia page: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Basically the number of ways to split a number `n` into `k` positive integers is `(n-1)C(k-1)` or `n-1` choose `k-1`. Thus, you can iterate for `k` = `1` to `n-d-1` to find the number of ways you can split `n-d-1` into any number of positive integers.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k) to find out how to efficiently calculate `nCk` for large `n` and `k` efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Certainly some  combinatoric math can solve this without even using code.  But the recursive challenge looked fun to try to code.

A  lightly tested, example - not much more efficient than OP's.
(Step 1, use more meaningful variable names)

```
unsigned long solve(unsigned sum_n, unsigned max_value_k, unsigned special_d) {
  if (sum_n == 0) return special_d == 0;
  unsigned long solutions = 0;

  // Improve efficiency, only loop up to min(k,n)
  if (max_value_k > sum_n) {
    max_value_k = sum_n;
  }

  // Will the loop contain d?
  if (max_value_k >= special_d) {
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= max_value_k; i++) {
      solutions += solve(sum_n - i, max_value_k,
          i == special_d ? 0 : special_d);
      solutions %= 1000000007;
    }
  }
  return solutions;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  unsigned n, k, d;
  for (n=0; n<100; n++) {
    printf("%u %lu\n", n, solve(n, 100, 1));
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  scanf("%u %u %u", &n, &k, &d);
  printf("%lu\n", solve(n, k, d));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's efficient enough (e.g. `n = k = 100, d = 5`).

Comment: @md5 Agree, hence the "not much more efficient than OP's.".  As OP has yet to post some test cases, this answer is useful to compare to a candidate faster answer  for functionality - hopefully this one is correct.  No point in a fast method if it is not functionally correct.

Comment: @chux...sorry for the late reply.....I have added some example test cases.